# how do I multiply values without giving the NaN error?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script to multiply values but gives me a NaN error, I need the Total Odds to be equal to 0 whenever the cart is empty and calculate the payout which is total Odds * stake amount, how do I make my script work?

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bet Plus 24/7</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javscript" src="script.js"></script>
    
    
</head>

<body style ="margin:10px;">


<div class="cart">

  <div class="title">Bet Slip</div>
  
  <div id="box" class="boxlit"></div>
  
  <br>

  <div>Total Odds: <b id="ct1"></b></div>

  <br>

  <div>(N$)Stake: <input id="stake" type="number" value="5"></input><span> NAD</span></div>

  <br>

  <div>Payout: <b id="payout"></b></div>

  <button class="bet1">Bet</button>

  <div class="footer"></div>

</div>


<br>

<table id="Table1" class="Fixtures-Table">
    
    <thead>

        <tr>
            
            <th>League</th>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Draw</th>
            <th>Away</th>
            <th>Kickoff</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>



    <tbody >

        <tr><th>AFF U19 Championship Group Stage<td id="label" >1<td id="label" >x<td id="label" >2</th></tr>
<tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">Myanmar U19 - Vietnam U19</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="9.00" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="4.60" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="1.29" /></td>
                <td class="label">7/8/2022 10:00</td> 
                
            </tr><tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">Philippines U19 - Indonesia U19</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="37.00" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="8.25" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="1.04" /></td>
                <td class="label">7/8/2022 15:00</td> 
                
            </tr><tr><th>Africa Women Cup of Nations<td id="label" >1<td id="label" >x<td id="label" >2</th></tr>
<tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">Burkina Faso - Uganda</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="2.65" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="2.85" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="2.55" /></td>
                <td class="label">7/8/2022 22:00</td> 
                
            </tr><tr>
            
                <td class="addItem">Morocco - Senegal</td> 
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="2.20" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="2.95" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="decimals" id="" value ="3.15" /></td>
                <td class="label">7/8/2022 22:00</td> 
                
            </tr>

</tbody>



        </table>
```

here is my script for adding to the cart

```
        <script>
        
        $(".decimals").each(function(index) {
              $(this).attr("id", index);
            });

        let $th = $('#Table1 thead th');
        
        $(".decimals").on('click', e => {
          
          let $btn = $(e.target);
          let $option = $(`.box[data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}"]`);
        
          let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
          let selectionIndex = $btn.closest('td').index();
        
          let match = $tr.find('td:first').text().trim();
          let result = $th.eq(selectionIndex).text().trim();
          let value = $btn.val();
        
          if ($option.length) {
            $option.remove();
            return;
            
          }
        
          $("#box").append(`<div class="box" data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}">${match}<br>${result}<div class="crtTotal">${value}</div></div>`);
        
        
/// this script calculates the Total Odds it needs to show value as 0 whenever the cart is empty
        
        $(this).click(function() { 
        
            let values = $('.crtTotal').map((i, el) => parseFloat(el.textContent)).get();
            let total = values.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
            $('#ct1').text(total.toFixed(2)).val
        
        
            })
        
            });
        
        
          </script>
```

here is the script for the payout calculation

```
<script>
        
        $(this).click(function() { 
        
        var x = parseInt($('#ct1').text());4
        
        var y = parseInt($('#stake').text());
        
        var net = x * y
        
        $("#payout").text(net)
        
        })
        
        </script>
```

Comment: you work on every click on holl screen, so if first time you click on screen and `$('#ct1').text()` this will return `empty string` and `parseInt($('#ct1').text())` will return `NaN` because `$('#ct1').text()` its value is string and parseInt ignores other than numbers in string.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable `totalcount` which will increment or decrement when you add or remove an item from the cart.

```html
<script>
  $(".decimals").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("id", index);
  });

  let $th = $('#Table1 thead th');
  // decalre Total value
  window.totalcount = 0;
  $(".decimals").on('click', e => {

    let $btn = $(e.target);
    let $option = $(`.box[data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}"]`);

    let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
    let selectionIndex = $btn.closest('td').index();

    let match = $tr.find('td:first').text().trim();
    let result = $th.eq(selectionIndex).text().trim();
    let value = $btn.val();

    if ($option.length) {
      $option.remove();
      return;

    }
    $("#box").append(`<div class="box" data-id="${$btn.prop('id')}">${match}<br>${result}<div class="crtTotal">${value}</div></div>`);
    // plus one when add one item to cart
    window.totalcount++;
    // Set value on total count
    $('#ct1').text(window.totalcount);
  });
</script>
```

And in your payout calculation you use `totalcount` variable.

```html
<script>
        
        $(this).click(function() { 
        
          var x = window.totalcount;

          var y = parseInt($('#stake').val() ?? 0);// Just to make sure that $('#stake') have value

          var net = x * y;

          $("#payout").text(net);       
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Good Day, The Payout is still giving a NaN error and when the cart is empty the total still shows the previous number before the click

Comment: @NdeapoSilvanus Hi I had edit my answer. Your `$('#stake').text()` need to change to `$('#stake').val()` because `.text()` will not work on input elements. `.text()` for getting innerText